# How can I populate data inside a LINQ .Select from the values of each character of a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection with question and answer data. Note that the value of Result is a string that represents the true or false values of the answers:

Here's a simple example:

```
List<ResultDTO> result1 = new List<ResultDTO> () {
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", Result="001", AnswerId= 1, AnswerText= "Aab1" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", Result="001", AnswerId= 2, AnswerText= "Aab2" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "abc", Result="001", AnswerId= 3, AnswerText= "Aab3" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", Result="110", AnswerId= 4, AnswerText= "Aab4" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", Result="110", AnswerId= 5, AnswerText= "Aab5" },
   new ResultDTO () { Id=1, Text= "def", Result="110", AnswerId= 6, AnswerText= "Aab6" }
};
```

In this example the AnswerId 3,4 and 5 will be correct

I am using the following code which groups by Id, Text and Result

```
var questions = result1
  .GroupBy(
    r => new { r.Id, r.Text, r.Result },
    (key, results) => new QuestionDTO {
      Id = key.Id,
      Text = key.Text,
      Answers = results
        .Select(r => new AnswerDTO { 
           AnswerId = r.AnswerId, 
           AnswerText = r.AnswerText,
           AnswerResult =  })
        .ToList()
    }
  )
  .ToList();
```

Can someone help tell me how I can populate the column AnswerResult. The data for this is going
to be in r.Result but I am not sure how to use the data

Answer (score 1):

key has all the properties you assigned in your group:

```
var questions = result1
    .GroupBy(
    r => new { r.Id, r.Text, r.Result },
    (key, results) => new QuestionDTO 
    {
        Id = key.Id,
        Text = key.Text,
        Answers = results
        .Select(r => new AnswerDTO 
        { 
            AnswerId = r.AnswerId, 
            AnswerText = r.AnswerText,
            AnswerResult = key.Result 
        })
        .ToList()
     }
  )
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Giannis - My problem is that the first column of the Result will be for the first answer. Second column for the second answer and the third column for the third answer. I think I will need to get the value of Result for position but how do I get that position inside the select ?